# Add style to the first element with class in the whole document

Tags: html, css

i am encountering a difficulty matching some elements in CSS with my structure.

This is my HTML (for example)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>parent</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="highlight-child">x</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="highlight-child">x</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="highlight-child">x</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="highlight-child">x</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I would like to the first `.hightlight-child` to be pink, and the last `.highlight-child` to be red. So i tried many solutions, it seems impossible to do it because the structure doest not allow it.

For example, this CSS does not work :

```
.highlight-child{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.highlight-child:first-child{
    background-color: pink;
}

.highlight-child:last-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can check a codepen here : https://codepen.io/ThbDms/pen/BaOagvv

Comment: In order for child-selector working correctly, your `highlight-child` need to be in same <div> (same container)